# How do I enable 1.5x scaling on a hidpi (4k) monitor on ubuntu 18.04.1lts?

Tags: google-chrome, display, display-resolution

I am running ubuntu on a 28 inch 4k (3840x2160) Dell display.  I want to enable 1.5x display scaling like it was possible to do in previous versions of ubuntu (unity) or at least make the window title-bars larger.  However the 200% scaling would make it equivalent to a 1080P display which would be a little large for this resolution.

Chrome and VSCODE so far have been able to get around this, possilby because they are based on electron?  I have attached a screenshot showing the settings and window size.

I have included a screenshot showing the window title-bar size of chrome vs ubuntu native decoration.  [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying a non-integer scaling factor is known as fractional scaling. If you search the web for that keyword, you'll see that the GNOME desktop unfortunately doesn't support it (yet).

Answer (score 2):

I recently had Ubuntu restart in my 4K Window and Chrome oddly for the first time ever ... (perhaps conspiracy theory here ... beware! ....
had its' main body scaled but the top bar and tabs and ... well all the top stuff, were tiny.

So here is an easy fix, if you are comfortable with terminal.

The problem is Chrome does NOT scale WITH UBUNTU - ODDLY!  So it is PURELY a ...
google-chrome-stable (as is my Ubuntu chrome's version issue)
...

So the easy fix in terminal! (I am sure there is an easy GUI way too but this worked for me flawlessly)
Open Google's settings file.

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
```

at the bottom is this line, "Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --incognito"
I put a # in front of it to "Comment" it out, ...

"# Commented out by Mark Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --incognito" (no quotes)

and I added this line.

Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --force-device-scale-factor=100 %U

the 100 is the number in question to change its scaling.
200 worked and then I set it to 100 and it worked!  So what number is really best I don't know kinda weird ... but now fine  ... nonetheless!