# Individual scaling on screens with different resolution with Kubuntu

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, multiple-monitors, display-resolution, scaling

I wanted to switch to Linux from Windows as I'm daily using Linux at work and I wanted a more efficient and streamlined os that I can customize for my needs.

I like the modern approach of KDE Plasma 5 so I went with Kubuntu.

I have a big 4K Monitor and a smaller 1080p Monitor. Starting up Kubuntu I had to realize that the scaling is wrong and that scaling can only be changed systemwide unlike Windows where I can change it for each monitor individually.

The NVIDIA Driver offers the same options as the system settings in the GUI.

I tried using xrandr for more settings outside of what the GUI offers. Firstly it doesn't work and screws up the display (the scaling is correct but the desktop only covers a quarter of the monitor) and secondly xrandr doesn't save its settings meaning a restart will set them to default again.

Is there any way to make scaling per monitor happening because if not its a big deal-breaker for me?

When I first got my 4K monitor Microsoft had a lot of problems with scaling and I was pissed at them back then but by now they do it without any problems. It would be an even bigger shame if Linux didn't sort it out until now as 4K Monitors are out for close to 7 years now.

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190011/dual-monitors-and-hidpi-display-struggling-to-scale-properly, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1100553/how-do-i-enable-1-5x-scaling-on-a-hidpi-4k-monitor-on-ubuntu-18-04-1lts, https://askubuntu.com/questions/844342/is-there-any-ubuntu-flavor-that-handles-hidpi-consistently